# How can i prevent my windows from showing screensaver or powering down from my application?

Tags: c#

I have a digital signage application that i want to run as a priority on the computer. I have now hooked into the win32 events (ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED) to prevent this. However i would like to get rid of this win32 call because i think thats the one that elevates the rights for my application so that it need to be run as an administrator.

Is there a managed way of doing the same? I mean, what is the media player etc. doing to prevent sleep/screensaver when you watch a movie?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SetThreadExecutionState function like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
public const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
public const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
public const uint ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040;

public void AllowStandbyMode(bool allow)
{
    if (allow)
    {
        // Set state back to normal
        SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS);
    }
    else
    {
        // Try this for vista, it will fail on XP
        if (SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED) == 0)
        {
            // Try XP variant as well just to make sure 
            SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
        }    
    }
}
```